# Hadoop MapReduce mapper read multiple line instead of one line

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am kind of new to Hadoop MapReduce. I am working on a project to read data files as below:

```
[Event "Rated Classical game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/j1dkb5dw"]
[White "BFG9k"]
[Black "mamalak"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2012.12.31"]
[UTCTime "23:01:03"]
[WhiteElo "1639"]
[BlackElo "1403"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+5"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-8"]
[ECO "C00"]
[Opening "French Defense: Normal Variation"]
[TimeControl "600+8"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 b6 3. a3 Bb7 4. Nc3 Nh6 5. Bxh6 gxh6 6. Be2 Qg5 7. Bg4 h5 8. Nf3 Qg6 9. Nh4 Qg5 10. Bxh5 Qxh4 11. Qf3 Kd8 12. Qxf7 Nc6 13. Qe8# 1-0
```

But I couldn't figure out how to read multiple lines in the mapper because mapper usually read once per line.
I've tried using NLineInputFormat, but it doesn't quite works.

Below is my code for my driver:
(I am trying on the mapper only, so I set reduce job to zero)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf("Usage: AvgWordLength <input dir> <output dir>\n");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Project: Chess Analysis");
    
    job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
    NLineInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 18);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
    job.setJarByClass(ChessAnalysis.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ChessMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ChessReducer.class);
    
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class); 
    
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

I will appreciate with all the help thanks.

Comment: Explain "doesn't work". That input format is correct, so how are you testing it? Is that your whole file, never anything larger? If so, I'd suggest writing/using a "whole file" input format https://stackoverflow.com/a/21554303/2308683

Comment: Doesn't work means that the mapper still read line by line. And no the whole file contains multiple block of data above. Potentially multiple GB of data per file. 
For my mapper, I want to context.write(<the winner>, <possibly an array of data>)

Comment: Is there no way to modify your file to change that input file to something better to parse before you write it to HDFS ? Otherwise, you're going to need to write your own input format. Also, your mapper output is Text, not an array. Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320325/nlineinputformat-not-working-in-spark

Comment: Is there a way to modify the file? I couldn't think of a way as for now. I guess I would look at sparks for now

Comment: Your file doesn't end up in HDFS on its own. Something puts it there. I'm suggesting that you parse the file before placing it in HDFS rather than working around mapreduce limitations afterwards. Spark isn't going to fix the issue since it also depends on InputFormat functions

Comment: I see that actually make sense. Thanks.